# How to convert .doc file to .pdf file in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi I am doing one application here I neeed to convert .doc file to pdf file,i tried but no idea any one did before please suggest me...thankyou

```
       public class ShootAndCropActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have good luck with [this lib](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/docx4j-from-github-in-eclipse/), available on GitHub. A how-to is presented in the article.

Comment: Great, thanks. If this answer helped you, maybe accept it or upvote it? Or both? Cheers.